# VS Code not Opening

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am New to coding. I opened vs code 2-3 after today to start my coding journey but when i opened it.
It shows black screen totally blank . I watched some youtube videos then on this problem and reinstall my vs code app but nothing happens then i use disable gpu before its name in properties with proper spellings and syntax did 2-3 times but nothing happens again then i use compatable mode in vistra and windows 8 but nothing happens again.

I really want to learn programming Plzz help me in solving this problem and in easy language i didn't understand high programmers language.

I am attaching some screenshots for your help to understand my problem better.

[image]
[image]

reinstall my vs code app
disable GPU
compatable mode in vistra and windows 8
nothing happens it didn't showing anything

Comment: Do you have any antivirus installed? if so, what if you try opening VS Code with it disabled?

Comment: Is your computer managed by a parent, employer, etc.?

Comment: Starball only McCafe is installed but it is sign out.

Comment: Samanthingamajig bro it's family computer all uses it but 90% of the time it is in my hands